# npm install -g @vue/cli 4 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 2 high) npm audit fix --force doesn't work

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, terminal, npm-install

I uninstall nodejs because i thought that will fix my problem but no. I only want to create a vue.js app in an empty folder but i have these errors lines when I enter `npm install -g @vue/cli`. It tells me there are 4 vulnerabilites and `npm audit fix --force` doesn't work

Error lines from `npm install -g @vue/cli`

`

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
changed 847 packages, and audited 848 packages in 26s

64 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

4 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 2 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

`

Error lines from `npm audit fix --force`

`npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\freir\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-08T13_17_58_614Z-debug-0.log`

When I enter `node -v` it tells me the right version of node and same thing for `npm -v`

i really need help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of my previous answers on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+vulnerabilities

TLDR: it's totally fine, you can move along. JavaScript is moving fast and there are probably millions of vulnerabilities but none of those will ever (or very unlikely at least) break anything into your app.

If there is something really critical, it will be fixed for you don't worry.